# VS2010 Professional - refresh error list

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to manually refresh or get VS to check code for errors in VS2010 Professional?

I was writing writing code for a creation of a new string in C#, something close to:

```
decimal[] totals = new decimals[4];
```

and got error in Error List, I've corrected mistake(changed decimals to "decimal") but error didn't disapear straight away, VS prevented me from debugging and error only disappeared after approx a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the project by pressing Shift+F6.